# what is the number of population for confidence level 95% and the width of 4

Tags: probability, statistics

I have my a level exam in two days and I have this question b ii and I am stuck on it I don't understand how the mark scheme got this answer (I will add a picture below) and any help is much appreciated.
[image]

and this is the mark scheme[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the width to be $4$ grams. That's like saying the margin of error is $2$ grams: that is it could be $2$ too low or $2$ too high. Thus we want the margin of error to be 2.

We know that when $n = 50$, the width of the confidence interval is 8 grams. Similar to above, that's saying the margin of error is $4$ grams.

Plugging this all into the equation for margin of error, or confidence intervals, we get two equations.

We know from the description of the problem, for the population of size $n=50$,
$$ 4 = \frac{z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{50}}. $$

We want to find population size $n^*$ so that
$$ 2 = \frac{z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{n^*}}.$$

Thus, we can see to get the left side on the second equation to look like the left side on the first equation, we need to multiply both sides by $2$ to get
$$ 4 = \frac{2 z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{n^*}}. $$

Now we can set the right side of the first equation equal to the right side of this equation. Then we can solve for $n$

$$ \frac{2 z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{n^*}} = \frac{z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{50}} \implies 2\sqrt{50} = \sqrt{n^*} \implies n^* = 200. $$

Comment: Ow my god thank you so much for answering but I am confused on one step how does it go from$$ = \frac{z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{50}} \implies 2\sqrt{50} = \sqrt{n^*} \implies n^* = 200. $$ Like the $2\sqrt{50}$

Comment: There is a $z^* \sigma$ in common both sides, so we divide that out. Then we cross-multiply. The notation it goes one equation to the next

Comment: Like so:
$$ \frac{2z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{n^*}} = \frac{z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{n^*}} \\
\implies 2 \sqrt{50} = \sqrt{n^*} \\ 
\implies n^* = 200$$

Comment: I see now thank you very much you don't know how much I appreciate it. But can I ask you a question how did you know we must use margin of error?

Comment: Confidence intervals are VERY tied to margin of error. The confidence interval of any mean estimate is $$ \left( \overline{X} - z^* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} , \overline{X} + z^* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \right). $$ The middle of the interval is $\overline{X}$. You can see that the lower bound on the interval is when we subtract off the margin of error, and the upper bound is when we add on the margin of error. Hence the margin of error must be $\dfrac{z^* \sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Comment: I see I mean I use this equation a lot but I don't know why I couldn't do this was it becausee it said width so means between to numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123695/discussion-between-pavan-c-and-sara).